# Java Building a Basic WebServer how do i send headers to browser

Tags: java, http

I'm still learning java and trying to build a basic WebServer using Sockets for now i have the server working and sending output data back to the browser but i'm unsure how to send the headers i thought they were just "\r\n\r\n" from the content body

This is how i'm writing to the browser currently

```
Socket socket = socketServer.accept();
System.out.println("Web Request From: "+socket.getInetAddress().toString());

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())
);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
Stirng output = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></body></html>"
out.write(output, 0, output.lenght());
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: Are you limited in what classes you can use?  There are higher level classes for handling headers.  I'll go chase them down if that's an option.

Comment: No i'm using NetBeans but i don't want to have to add a library to Java i want to build it as native as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your forced to send the HTTP information first

```
out.println("HTTP/1.0 200");
```

is required before any other codes send or the main body

Answer (score 1):

Put the headers in the output string, separated from each other by `\r\n` and from the main body by `\r\n\r\n`. Or, with the PrintWriter just print them one by one, an empty line, and then the body.

Comment: this does not work i get `Content-Type: text/html` inside my output rendered by the browser

Comment: Did you add an _empty_ line after the headers? _Two_ `\r\n`s in a row?

Comment: yeah, the problem was missing the HTTP/1.0 stuff

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/elonen/nanohttpd/blob/master/NanoHTTPD.java). Its a one file Web server and its a lot of fun to play with. They are sending headers back, so you should be able to look at their code fairly easily and see what they are doing.

Comment: there is a lot of code in that file :) im reading though it any pointers on where the output is created lol

Comment: Thank you i was missing `out.println("HTTP/1.0 200");` before i started sending headers back